# kubernetes DNS does not work in react app

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to deploy my simple web application using Kubernetes.
I completed making the Kubernetes cluster and successfully exposed my react app using ingress.
But it seems that the domain URL of backend service received from manifest file's "env" field does not work.

Following is the manifest file of react application.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: recofashion-client
  labels:
    app: recofashion-client
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: recofashion-client
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000

---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: recofashion-client
  labels:
    name: recofashion-client
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: recofashion-client
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: recofashion-client
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: recofashion/client-runtime
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        env:
        - name: NODE_ENV
          value: production
        - name: REACT_APP_API_V1_ENDPOINT
          value: http://recofashion-api/api/v1
```

And I think there is no problem in k8s DNS itself. I tried to send request using curl in my "recofashion-client" pod, and it seems to work as I intended.

```
curl http://recofashion-api/api/v1/user/me
{"timestamp":"2020-02-03T06:55:20.748+0000","status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Access Denied","path":"/api/v1/user/me"}
```

But when I try to send request in the browser, it fails like this:

[image]

And I'm receiving the external environment variables in react app from k8s like this:

```
const response = await getWithAuth(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_V1_ENDPOINT}/user/me`)
```

So what's the problem??? I searched internet a lot, but I couldn't get any appopriate answer...

++ the manifest file of ingress

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: recofashion-client
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: it will not work (if you r running your browser outside your cluster host machine). you can use service node port to access this api. can you show me the output of command <kubectl get services | grep "recofashion-client" >

Comment: @Munish thanks for replying! information about recofashion-client service is as following:
recofashion-client   NodePort    10.15.250.96   <none>        80:30590/TCP   102m

Comment: can you try this url on browser ::: http://<k8s-master-node-ip>:30590/api/v1/user/login

Comment: @Munish it's confusing... I want to access to "recofashion-api" service, but 30590 is the NodePort of "recofashion-client".. I want the api to be accessed only internally, so  I determined the type of api service as Cluster-IP. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: You mentioned using an Ingress. Can you share its descriptor ?

Comment: You say the app is to be accessed locally, Do you mean your internal LAN? Are you running the nodes on your local farm? Please Explain current environment to help us to replicate your scenario.

Comment: @MarcABOUCHACRA Ok. I appended it to my post.

Comment: @willrof No, I'm trying to make k8s cluster using GKE, so it's not my local farm. And I meant that I want the api service to be accessed only in the same cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on all informations provided I managed to reproduce your scenario using GKE.

**TL;DR:**

- Yes, the correct service-type for your **api-service** is `ClusterIP`
- The correct service-type for your **api-client** for outside access  is `LoadBalancer`, [doc here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps#access_your_service_2).
- Your **ENV** `REACT_APP_API_V1_ENDPOINT` must point to **Api Service** address, not to deploy or pod address. (i.e: `value: http://recofashion-api-svc`)
- You cannot use cluster DNS externally.

### **Reproduction**

Since I don't have your react app, I'm using an echo-app to simulate the two parts of the communication. This way I'm manually reproducing what your application would do by itself.

- First between `internet` and `recofashion-client`
- Second between `recofashion-client` and `recofashion-api`.

**`recofashion-client` - FrontEnd**:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: recofashion-client
  labels:
    name: recofashion-client
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: recofashion-client
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: recofashion-client
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: mendhak/http-https-echo
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: NODE_ENV
          value: production
        - name: REACT_APP_API_V1_ENDPOINT
          value: http://recofashion-api-svc
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: recofashion-cli-svc
  labels:
    app: recofashion-client
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: recofashion-client
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 80
```

**`recofashion-api` - backend API**:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: recofashion-api
  labels:
    name: recofashion-api
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: recofashion-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: recofashion-api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api-web
        image: mendhak/http-https-echo
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: NODE_ENV
          value: production
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: recofashion-api-svc
  labels:
    app: recofashion-api
spec:
  selector:
    app: recofashion-api
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Note: **I kept your Ingress intact.**

**Now to the terminal:**

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                                       STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
gke-cluster-1-default-pool-e0523823-06jt   Ready    <none>   2d    v1.15.7-gke.23
gke-cluster-1-default-pool-e0523823-vklh   Ready    <none>   2d    v1.15.7-gke.23

$ kubectl apply -f recofashion-full.yaml 
deployment.apps/recofashion-client created
service/recofashion-cli-svc created
deployment.apps/recofashion-api created
service/recofashion-api-svc created
ingress.extensions/reco-ingress created

$ kubectl get all 
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/recofashion-api-784b4d9897-9256q      1/1     Running   0          12m
pod/recofashion-api-784b4d9897-ljkfs      1/1     Running   0          12m
pod/recofashion-client-75579c8499-wd5vj   1/1     Running   0          12m
pod/recofashion-client-75579c8499-x766s   1/1     Running   0          12m

NAME                          TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE
service/kubernetes            ClusterIP      10.0.0.1     <none>          443/TCP          2d
service/recofashion-api-svc   ClusterIP      10.0.4.73    <none>          80/TCP           12m
service/recofashion-cli-svc   LoadBalancer   10.0.3.133   35.239.58.188   3000:31814/TCP   12m

NAME                                 READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/recofashion-api      2/2     2            2           13m
deployment.apps/recofashion-client   2/2     2            2           13m

NAME                                            DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/recofashion-api-784b4d9897      2         2         2       13m
replicaset.apps/recofashion-client-75579c8499   2         2         2       13m

$ curl http://35.239.58.188:3000  
{
  "path": "/",
  "headers": {
    "host": "35.239.58.188:3000",
    "user-agent": "curl/7.66.0",
  },
  "method": "GET",
  "body": "",
  "hostname": "35.239.58.188",
  "ip": "::ffff:10.8.1.1",
  "protocol": "http",
  "os": {
    "hostname": "recofashion-client-75579c8499-x766s"
  }
}
```

[image: Client Access from browser from outside network]

So far no problems, we are able to `curl` from outside to the `recofashion-client`.

**Now let's connect inside `recofashion-client` and try to connect to `recofashion-api` using the ENV created during deploy:**

```
❯ kubectl exec recofashion-client-75579c8499-x766s -it sh
/app # apk update && apk add curl
OK: 10 MiB in 20 packages

/app # env
REACT_APP_API_V1_ENDPOINT=http://recofashion-api-svc
NODE_ENV=production

/app # curl $REACT_APP_API_V1_ENDPOINT
{
  "path": "/",
  "headers": {
    "host": "recofashion-api-svc",
    "user-agent": "curl/7.61.1",
    "accept": "*/*"
  },
  "method": "GET",
  "body": "",
  "hostname": "recofashion-api-svc",
  "ip": "::ffff:10.8.1.21",
  "protocol": "http",
  "os": {
    "hostname": "recofashion-api-784b4d9897-9256q"
  }
}

/app # nslookup recofashion-api-svc
Name:      recofashion-api-svc
Address 1: 10.0.4.73 recofashion-api-svc.default.svc.cluster.local
```

When we use the `api-service` name in the ENV `value`, it resolves the DNS because the service is the responsible for directing the load to the PODs.

- Follow this steps and you can be sure that your K8s configuration won't be an issue.

**Edit:**

- If your React is outside the cluster, the best way you can access the backend-api is creating a service to reach to the backend pods and address your request the exposed ip and port of the service, just like we did.
- Now, if you want this to work with external DNS names for the whole cluster, take a look on some external dns projects like this: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/nginx-ingress.md

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. I followed the steps you suggetsed, but it seems like the DNS of k8s still does not work in the browser.. As @saiteja says, the DNS would not work because my react app would not be running in my cluster.

Comment: @geunyoung If your React is outside the cluster, you cannot call it by DNS name. You can move your react to kubernetes or you can change your calls to not use internal DNS. Also please consider voting on the answers you received so far.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the micro service that is restricted to cluster

`recofashion-api` can be resolved within the kubernetes cluster only not from outside

this line of code will be run in the browser who is accessing your site

```
const response = await getWithAuth(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_V1_ENDPOINT}/user/me`)
```

so the browser cant resolve `recofashion-api` and your get method is failing

Comment: oh I got it,, so you mean the api service also should be a NodePort rather than Cluster-IP?? How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you're not binding your ingress to any host name. So in order to access your service from the outside, you need to use the IP address associated to that ingress.
Using the service name won't have any affect from outside the cluster.

As the documentation says :

> An optional host. In this example, no host is specified, so the rule applies to all inbound HTTP traffic through the IP address specified. If a host is provided (for example, foo.bar.com), the rules apply to that host.

In summary, if you have this configuration :

```
kubectl get ingress ingress # btw, this is a very bad name for your ingress !

NAME           HOSTS     ADDRESS           PORTS     AGE
ingress        *         107.178.254.228   80        59s
```

You should be able to access your service with this url : `http://107.178.254.228/`

You can find more info about how `Ingress` works (and this example in particulary) in the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#types-of-ingress)

**After your clarification about the API, here is some precision :**

As @saiteja pakalapati said, you can't access your API from outside your cluster using a `ClusterIp`. While using a `NodePort` can be a solution, you can just keep using your already existing `Ingress`. Example below :

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: recofashion-client
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /api
        backend:
          serviceName: recofashion-api
          servicePort: 80 # change with whatever port you're using
```

Now, in your code, in order to call the API, you'll need to use the ingress IP (as you're already doing with the client) and the path to your api : `http://107.178.254.228/api`

Comment: I can't understand why you're talking about the ingress of 'recofahsion-client' .. Surely I can access my 'recofashion-client' service via the address provided by the ingress. But the problem is that the pods in "recofashion-client" cannot access to "recofahsion-api" service via k8s DNS. And I'm asking if I should change the type of "recofashion-api" from Cluster-IP to NodePort, so that the service can be accessed outside the cluster.

Comment: Ok my bad, as you didn't share the descriptor for your `recofashion-api` service, I assumed it was just a typo. So as @saiteja pakalapati if you're trying to access a `ClusterIP` service from outside the cluster, then it won't work. Using a `NodePort` can be a solution, or you can just add an `Ingress` configuration to your API.

Comment: I edited the answer in order to add some clarification.